# calculating variance with mysql week over week

Tags: mysql, sql, date, window-functions, domo

I need to display week over week difference with mysql in `Week Over Week Users` column. My data looks like the following:

```
Date          Users          Week Over Week Users 
06-01-2019    10              10
06-08-2019    15              15
06-15-2019    5               5
```

Currently, `Week Over Week Users` only reflects the data that I have in `Users` column. The desired output would be:

```
Date          Users          Week Over Week Users 
06-01-2019    10              10
06-08-2019    15              5
06-15-2019    5               -10
```

Basically if on the second week the number of users grew up to 15 users, then I need to display 5 (as in +5 users since last week, so `new week Users - last week Users` would be the formula)

Here is my code:

```
(
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN WEEK(`Date`) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE()) THEN `Users`
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) - SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN WEEK(`Date`) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE()) - 1 THEN `Users`
            ELSE 0
        END
    )
)
```

But it doesn't work as it duplicates the Users column.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running? `select version()` can tell you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am running this in DOMO. So this is the snippet of code for the specific column.

Answer (score 0):

You want `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (users - lag(users, 1, 0) over (order by date)) as week_over_week
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 5.x, where window functions such as `lag()` are not available, you can use a correlated subquery to get the "previous" value:

```
select
    t.date,
    t.users,
    t.users - coalesce(
        (
            select t1.users 
            from mytable t1 
            where t1.date < t.date 
            order by t1.date desc
            limit 1
        ),
        0
    ) week_over_week_users
from mytable t
```